# Connecting 2 routers on one mobile network to amplify internet speed on 2 PCs?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I'm using T mobile internet router with sim card in it and I have one additional router without sim card. I wish to somehow use that additional router to amplify my internet speed which is almost halved when PCs that are LAN connected to router are simultaneously in use on one router, is it possible to somehow connect each PC to its own router while using the mobile network of main router (with sim card in it) or maybe somehow use additional router to amplify main router?

Comment: You cannot magically use a second router to increase your internet speed ...

Comment: Well… the 'magic' comes when you buy a 2nd SIM card for the other router & set half the devices to use that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. The speed limiting factor is the single connection to the mobile network that your devices are sharing. An additional router won't change that.